# How to get Wikipedia lists from Python?

Tags: python, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I'm trying to write a program that gets a list of songs from a given album or soundtrack. I've been trying to do that by using Wikipedia, and I've found 2 modules that are supposed to do the job: [wikipedia](https://pypi.org/project/wikipedia/) and [wikipedia-api](https://pypi.org/project/Wikipedia-API/). Unfortunately, neither of those get the element of the article I'm looking for, instead choosing to just skip over it. That's really not helpful at all for me, obviously. So what I want to know is: Is there a module that will get lists from a Wikipedia article? Or do I have to use the original Wikipedia APIs and create one myself? I'm trying to avoid getting the raw html and parsing that because it would be complicated and probably unnecessary.

Here's some sample code you can try, it uses the wikipedia module (pip install wikipedia) but the error is the same on both modules.

```
import wikipedia
article = wikipedia.search("civil war soundtrack")[0] # I've already checked this, the searching is definitely accurate and isn't the source of the problem
pg = wikipedia.page(article)
print(pg.text)
```

When it prints the text, instead of printing the table under the section "Track listing",  it prints the line about the composer and skips the list entirely.

Thanks in advance!

Note: If I don't reply right away, it's because I'm asleep, it's late here so I'll check everything in the morning

Note 2: If I'm doing anything wrong in terms of how I ask the question, feedback is welcome! I've been downvoted for questions in the past and the reasons continue to elude me.

Comment: I've had these problems with `wikipedia` package, they completely ignore key elements in the page like tables for some reason. So I've switched to using `BeautifulSoup` for wikipedia table scraping. Don't know anything about `wikipedia-api` if the problem is there too

Comment: See an example of this issue here: https://github.com/goldsmith/Wikipedia/issues/111

Comment: Yeah, and it's made worse by the fact that the thing I'm trying to find isn't exactly a table, as in it's not identified by class='wikitable'. So even when I use something that can find tables, it can't find the list I'm looking for.

Comment: HTML parsing is probably your best bet. It's easier and has better tooling than the parsing of wikitext tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried following libraries and none of them support the extraction of tables:

- wikipedia
- wikipedia-api
- MediaWikiAPI

People have had the same issue as you and one guy suggests a possible solution to your problem using MediaWikiAPI and Beautiful soup:

```
# load page 
mediawikiapi = MediaWikiAPI()
test_page = mediawikiapi.page(PageWithTables)

# scrape the HTML with BeautifulSoup to find tables
soup = BeautifulSoup(test_page.html(), 'html.parser')
tables = soup.findAll("table", { "class" : "wikitable" })

# select target table and apply custom function to export it to pandas
target_table = tables[0]
df_test = wikitable_to_dataframe(target_table)
```

Source: https://github.com/goldsmith/Wikipedia/issues/111

Comment: Okay, so I tried that and I found out some valuable information that makes everything this much harder: the list I'm trying to get apparently isn't a wikitable. So that solution doesn't work. I checked the article that I linked in the question, I went into the part where you can edit the section. There, it is supposed to say class="wikitable", but it doesn't. That's probably why everything I've tried doesn't work.